# Neither BindingResult Nor Plain Target Object for bean name error - Does the bean class name matter?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have seen a few postings related to this.  However, I seem to be seeing something that I do not understand. Following is a section of my code:

```
package com.mvctest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.dao.User;


@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping("/newAccount")
public String createAccountScreen (Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    return "createaccountscreen";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/createAccount", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createAccount (@Valid User user, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        List<ObjectError> errors = result.getAllErrors();
        for(ObjectError error : errors) {
            System.out.println(error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        return "createaccountscreen";
    }
    return "accountcreated";
}
```

Then in my jsp file createaccountscreen.jsp I have the following:

```
<sf:form method="post"
    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/createAccount"
    commandName="user">
```

This works fine.

However if I changed the addAttribute () call as following

```
model.addAttribute("myuser", new User());
```

and changed the commandName in the jsp to

```
<sf:form method="post"
    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/createAccount"
    commandName="myuser">
```

I get the following error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'myuser' available as request attribute

Essentially, I replace 'user' with 'myuser'.

Bean class is 'User'.  Does that mean the commandName needs to be 'user'?

Comment: you are getting the error when you do the GET or POST?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Can you confirm that _essentially_ is really just that change?

Comment: I am using POST.  Only the 2 changes I have mentioned (one with the call to addAddtribute and the other for the commandName in the jsp file)

Comment: Yes and no. The problem is your code is flawed. Your `createAccount` method should have a `@ModelAttribute`. This does a couple of things, first it looks for a attribute with a certain name (by default the name of the method argument) if it isn't there it will construct one. If it isn't there no object will be added to the model, at least not under the name you specified. If you want to make sure you use a certain object add the `name` to the annotation. i.e. `@ModelAttribute("myuser")`.

Comment: It works once I add the ModelAttribute annotation. You said Yes and No. Does the 'Yes' mean that Bean class name is used in the absence of ModelAttribute annotation? Thanks.